# Passing page ID to wp_head/wp_footer

Tags: php, wordpress

What I'm trying to do is have a user select a page from a drop-down menu when writing a post or page in WordPress and then showing that selected page (user_selection) as an extra loop.

What I have is this and it's working fine when used in a theme:

```
<?php $user_selection = get_post_meta($wp_query->post->ID, 'user_selection', true); ?>
        <?php 
        $id = $user_selection; 
        $post = get_post($id); 
        $content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); 
        echo $content;  
        ?>
```

But when used in a plugin and added to wp_head or wp_footer, then the ID won't get passed along. I've read that WordPress doesn't pass variables like that, so I'm (quite) a bit stuck.

Any help on how to get around this would be appreciated.

### --------

**Update.** I got it to work by using:

```
<?php global $wp_query; $user_selection = get_post_meta($wp_query->post->ID, 'user_selection', true); ?>    
<?php $id=$user_selection;
$post = get_post($id);
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
echo $content; ?>
```

Everything is fine except that on posts that already exist, the slide-out page defaults to the current post/page (should default to none). When the post is saved, then it works, but that would mean re-saving all the posts, which would be nonsense :) What am I missing?

`wp_dropdown_pages` in the backend is entered like this:

```
<?php wp_dropdown_pages( array( 'name' => 'user_selection', 'id' => 'user_selection', 'selected' => $selected, 'show_option_none' => '-- no selection --', 'option_none_value' => '-1' ) ); ?>
```

Thanks!

### ----------

**Update 2.** I think I got it:

```
<?php global $wp_query; $user_selection = get_post_meta($wp_query->post->ID, 'user_selection', true); ?>
        <?php $var = 0; if (empty($user_selection)) { ?>
        NO SELECTION MADE
        <?php } else { ?>
            <?php 
            $id=$user_selection; 
            $post = get_post($id); 
            $content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); 
            echo $content;  
            ?>
        <?php } ?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: If it's not in the loop, it won't have access to `$wp_query`. You might be able to use `$post` instead - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/$post. You'd need to declare it as a global in your function, and rename your current `$post` variable.

Comment: Appreciate the help, I'm quite green in this area. This didn't do it though: `<?php $user_selection = get_post_meta($wp_query->post->ID, 'user_selection', true); ?>
<?php 
global $post;
$id = $user_selection;
$postid = get_post($id);
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
echo $content;
?>`

Comment: So check first if the page exists, then bypass the function and set it to none, otherwise run the function. Quite a challenge you have going here.

Comment: Any chance for code? I'm too green at this..

Comment: I think I got it. Can you check update 2 please in the post above and see if that looks good? Or is there a more efficient way of going about it... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In the form that passes the info, add a hidden input field, for *example* `<input type='hidden' id='id' name='id' value='<php echo $post->ID;>?'/>`. The you will be able to query the id.

Comment: The user selected option is coming from wp_dropdown_pages. Adding    `'type' => 'hidden'`    to it didn't do it.

Comment: Hmm. Add print_r($_POST) or print_r($_GET) to see if anything is being passed. I must add I am not too sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: What I want to do is allow users to select any page while writing a post or page (through `wp_dropdown_pages` which is in a metabox), and then the selected page content will be shown in a slide-out that users can activate. So far I can echo the ID of the selected page correctly with the following snippet, but not the actual content: `<?php
   global $wp_query;
   $postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
   echo get_post_meta($postid, 'my_meta_box_select', true);
   wp_reset_query();
   ?>`

Comment: Ok. So you can echo the post_id. So then just use `$id=get_post_meta($idofselectedpage, 'user_selection',true)`, then `$post = get_post($id);`, and then simply `the_content();`?

Comment: Can you please see the updated question regarding the default selection?